# Generating random numbers in Julia

Tags: random, julia

How to generate a real random number in range [-1, 1] in Julia?

Sorry, I'm just starting working in Julia and I couldn't find a right answer. For example I tried

```
rand(Float16, [-1,1], 1)
```

but I get `ERROR: MethodError` every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating e.g. 10 random numbers between -1 and 1, using broadcasting

```
julia> rand(10) .* rand((-1,1), 10)
10-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.7832605719765726
  0.11799399505997143
  0.49379156313102823
 -0.4481589093858642
 -0.9394405800834137
  0.12834147407759333
 -0.9643503751879805
 -0.6624220140320877
  0.4220815095109952
  0.16949781166834121
```

Comment: Note that this is quite a bit slower than the simple `2rand() - 1`, and also needlessly allocates an extra array in `[-1, 1]`. If you go for this I'd at least use a tuple here `(-1, 1)` to avoid that unnecessary allocation (a quick benchmarking suggests that it shaves off about half the runtime).

Comment: @NilsGudat Changed to tuple. Often one needs more than one random number and this might be an easy interface to get them. Applying this once the added cost is negligible.

Comment: If you want several random numbers, use `2 .* rand(10) .- 1`. Creating two random arrays seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

`rand()` returns a random number in `[0, 1)`, so the easiest thing you could do is

```
2rand() - 1
```

When you give an argument to `rand(x)` it generally means something like "return a random sample from `x`. As an example, `rand(1:10)` means "pick an integer between 1 and 10 (inclusive) at random:

```
julia> rand(1:10)
2
```

The second positional argument to `rand` is the number of samples, so `rand(1:10, 3)` will pick 3 random numbers (with replacement):

```
julia> rand(1:10, 3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
  6
  5
 10
```

If you wanted to be more explicit about the distribution you're sampling from you could use the `Distributions` package:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> rand(Uniform(-1, 1), 3)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
  0.13509110532903756
 -0.026048031817401895
 -0.5490076326320161
```

Here we pass a `Distribution` object as the first argument, which means `rand` will sample from this distribution according to the pdf defined in `Distributions`.

We could go on for quite a bit longer as your question turns out to be quite a deep one when one considers the limitations of floating point arithmetic. The Julia community being the Julia community there are some lengthy discussions on Discourse about this topic, here's one I found at random (no pun intended):

https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-create-a-random-uniform-distribution-between-but-excluding-0-and-10/21908/2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create random values of type `Float16` you have at least these two options:

```
julia> 2*rand(Float16) - 1
Float16(-0.952)
```

Or using Distributions.jl

```
julia> d = Uniform{Float16}(-1, 1);

julia> rand(d)
0.3907014142060643

julia> rand(d) |> typeof
Float64
```